# Return rows for maximum column value having same value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database table like follows:

Create table #temp(ID INT, Number1 INT, Number2 INT)

INSERT INTO #temp(111, 123, 10)

INSERT INTO #temp(111, 223, 10)

INSERT INTO #temp(111, 323, 10)

INSERT INTO #temp(112, 123, 11)

INSERT INTO #temp(112, 223, 11)

INSERT INTO #temp(112, 333, 11)

INSERT INTO #temp(113, 124, 12)

INSERT INTO #temp(113, 126, 12)

INSERT INTO #temp(114, 128, 121)

I have been working on a query but still no luck. I am looking for to return the following result:

ID   Number1  Number2

111      323         10

112   333      11

113   126      12

114      128    121

In the result set need to return the row with maximum value of column Number1 for the same ID value.

Comment: what did you try so far? What is the issue, are you getting an error/

Comment: I tried using Select MAX(Number1), ID, Number2 from #temp. But it returns only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL fixes your SQL :-) and I think returns the answer you are after:

```
DECLARE @temp table (ID INT, Number1 INT, Number2 INT);
INSERT INTO @temp (ID,Number1, Number2) VALUES (111, 123, 10)
INSERT INTO @temp (ID,Number1, Number2) VALUES (111, 223, 10)
INSERT INTO @temp (ID,Number1, Number2) VALUES (111, 323, 10)
INSERT INTO @temp (ID,Number1, Number2) VALUES (112, 123, 11)
INSERT INTO @temp (ID,Number1, Number2) VALUES (112, 223, 11)
INSERT INTO @temp (ID,Number1, Number2) VALUES (112, 333, 11)
INSERT INTO @temp (ID,Number1, Number2) VALUES (113, 124, 12)
INSERT INTO @temp (ID,Number1, Number2) VALUES (113, 126, 12)
INSERT INTO @temp (ID,Number1, Number2) VALUES (114, 128, 121)


SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID, T1.Number1, T1.Number2
FROM @temp T1
JOIN @temp T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.Number1=(SELECT MAX(Number1) FROM @temp T3 WHERE T3.ID=T1.ID)
```

All the best,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Max(Number1) as Number1, Number2 FROM #temp group by ID, Number2
```

I believe you are looking for the `GROUP` clause. It returns this:

```
111 323 10
112 333 11
113 126 12
114 128 121
```

Thank you @MichaelMoreno for pointing it out. I assumed that was a typo on the OP's part and I didnt post that as the solution. He was really asking for the way to `SELECT`. Here is the corrected code:

```
Create table #temp(ID INT, Number1 INT, Number2 INT)

INSERT INTO #temp values(111, 123, 10)

INSERT INTO #temp values(111, 223, 10)

INSERT INTO #temp values(111, 323, 10)

INSERT INTO #temp values(112, 123, 11)

INSERT INTO #temp values(112, 223, 11)

INSERT INTO #temp values(112, 333, 11)

INSERT INTO #temp values(113, 124, 12)

INSERT INTO #temp values(113, 126, 12)

INSERT INTO #temp values(114, 128, 121)
```